# DateTimeOffset(7) like from MSSQL to python datetime?

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc, python-datetime, datetimeoffset

How to convert this string `2017-10-13 15:30:00.0000000 +00` (<= seven (7) zero before `%z`) to python datetime format.

this is the latest error I got:

```
dt=datetime.datetime.strptime(f,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %z')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\_strptime.py", line 565, in _strptime_datetime
        tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
      File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\_strptime.py", line 362, in _strptime
        (data_string, format))
    ValueError: time data '2017-10-13 15:30:00.000000 +00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %z'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using an old ODBC driver (e.g., the ancient `DRIVER=SQL Server`) then you should always get a string representation of the DATETIMEOFFSET(7) value that is exactly 34 characters long:

```
2017-10-13 15:30:00.0000000 +00:00
```

All you need to do is trim out the seventh decimal place and remove the colon from the offset ...

```python
s = '2017-10-13 15:30:00.0000000 +00:00'
f = s[:26] + s[27:31] + s[32:]
print(repr(f))
# '2017-10-13 15:30:00.000000 +0000'
```

... and then the string will parse correctly

```python
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(f,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %z')
print(repr(dt))
# datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 13, 15, 30, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

If you switch to a newer ODBC driver that recognizes DATETIMEOFFSET columns and returns them natively then you can use a pyodbc [Output Converter function](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Using-an-Output-Converter-function) to handle it.